# Stimulsoft : Cannot render barcode in first print preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, report, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft Reports in a MVC web application. There is a `CODE128C` barcode in a report which contains 4 business object in every page(every item has one barcode).

When I clicked "Print with preview" button in "Print Viewer" from within web portal, only first page items have rendered barcode and other have an empty barcode! It's very strange that when I do it again(close print dialog and open it again with clicking "Print with preview") barcodes in all page will be rendered!

If there is only one user, we could FORCE him to open print preview twice! :) But we have very ignorant users who can waste a lot of paper!

Is it a bug in Stimulsoft? Or I must change something in Report Designer? Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE :**
Here Is a sample of the report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StiSerializer version="1.02" type="Net" application="StiReport">
  <Dictionary Ref="1" type="Dictionary" isKey="true">
    <BusinessObjects isList="true" count="1">
      <ExitLicense Ref="2" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiBusinessObject" isKey="true">
        <Alias>ExitLicense</Alias>
        <BusinessObjects isList="true" count="0" />
        <Category>PrintVm</Category>
        <Columns isList="true" count="4">
          <value>ExitLicenseId,System.Int64</value>
          <value>ContractNumber,System.String</value>
          <value>CompanyName,System.String</value>
          <value>CeoName,System.String</value>
        </Columns>
        <Dictionary isRef="1" />
        <Guid>f04db6f6af57437ab6b3ec7eeecfdf44</Guid>
        <Name>ExitLicense</Name>
      </ExitLicense>
    </BusinessObjects>
    <Databases isList="true" count="0" />
    <DataSources isList="true" count="0" />
    <Relations isList="true" count="0" />
    <Report isRef="0" />
    <Resources isList="true" count="0" />
    <Variables isList="true" count="1">
      <value>,IndustrialEstateName,IndustrialEstateName,,System.String,,False,False,False,False</value>
    </Variables>
  </Dictionary>
  <EngineVersion>EngineV2</EngineVersion>
  <GlobalizationStrings isList="true" count="0" />
  <MetaTags isList="true" count="0" />
  <Pages isList="true" count="1">
    <Page1 Ref="3" type="Page" isKey="true">
      <Border>None;Black;2;Solid;False;4;Black</Border>
      <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
      <Components isList="true" count="1">
        <DataBand1 Ref="4" type="DataBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
          <BusinessObjectGuid>f04db6f6af57437ab6b3ec7eeecfdf44</BusinessObjectGuid>
          <ClientRectangle>0,0.15,8.5,1.35</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="1">
            <BarCode1 Ref="5" type="Stimulsoft.Report.BarCodes.StiBarCode" isKey="true">
              <BackColor>Transparent</BackColor>
              <BarCodeType Ref="6" type="Stimulsoft.Report.BarCodes.StiCode128cBarCodeType" isKey="true" />
              <ClientRectangle>4.9,0.35,2.1,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Code>{ExitLicense.ExitLicenseId}</Code>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>B Yekan,9.75,Regular,Point,False,178</Font>
              <ForeColor>Black</ForeColor>
              <HorAlignment>Center</HorAlignment>
              <Name>BarCode1</Name>
              <Page isRef="3" />
              <Parent isRef="4" />
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </BarCode1>
          </Components>
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <DataSourceName isNull="true" />
          <Filters isList="true" count="0" />
          <Name>DataBand1</Name>
          <Page isRef="3" />
          <Parent isRef="3" />
          <Sort isList="true" count="0" />
        </DataBand1>
      </Components>
      <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
      <Guid>6743a7157e964eb5b4f79986bea69e48</Guid>
      <Margins>0,0,0.2,0.2</Margins>
      <Name>Page1</Name>
      <PageHeight>11</PageHeight>
      <PageWidth>8.5</PageWidth>
      <PaperSize>Letter</PaperSize>
      <Report isRef="0" />
      <Watermark Ref="7" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiWatermark" isKey="true">
        <Font>Arial,100</Font>
        <TextBrush>[50:0:0:0]</TextBrush>
      </Watermark>
    </Page1>
  </Pages>
  <PreviewSettings>268435455</PreviewSettings>
  <PrinterSettings Ref="8" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Print.StiPrinterSettings" isKey="true" />
  <ReferencedAssemblies isList="true" count="8">
    <value>System.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Drawing.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Windows.Forms.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Data.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Xml.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Controls.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Base.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Report.Dll</value>
  </ReferencedAssemblies>
  <ReportAlias>Report</ReportAlias>
  <ReportChanged>1/24/2018 2:30:06 PM</ReportChanged>
  <ReportCreated>1/24/2018 2:19:05 PM</ReportCreated>
  <ReportFile>D:\Reports\ExitLicense.mrt</ReportFile>
  <ReportGuid>7e8a339e3b61494b8f5e88509c3c08ef</ReportGuid>
  <ReportImage isNull="true" />
  <ReportName>Report</ReportName>
  <ReportUnit>Inches</ReportUnit>
  <ReportVersion>2016.3.0</ReportVersion>
  <Script>using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Stimulsoft.Controls;
using Stimulsoft.Base.Drawing;
using Stimulsoft.Report;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Dialogs;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Components;

namespace Reports
{
    public class Report : Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport
    {
        public Report()        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
        #endregion StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
    }
}
</Script>
  <ScriptLanguage>CSharp</ScriptLanguage>
  <Styles isList="true" count="0" />
</StiSerializer>
```

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong in your report.
Do you use DataBands? It will be possible to give you exact answer if you send a sample project.

Comment: @HighAley Yes I'm using DataBands. I create a fresh report that contain only one barcode object in each databand item. But the problem still exists. Based on my experience if I go through the last page before I print the report, this problem will not occur and all barcodes will render correctly. I think there must be an option either in code or in report designer to force stimulsoft load all pages while user perform a print